# Saving Matrix within Function to Parent Environment

Tags: r, matrix, environment

So I currently have several functions where I want to modify a matrix that was created outside the function, in order to use it as a counting variable for things that happen inside the function. The matrix is named cost_counter, and I want to add to it when certain events occur inside of multiple functions. However, I'd like the solution to still be able to be used in foreach() and be parallelizable.

I know that using <<- is not recommended, however I can't figure out how to use assign() to modify an existing matrix. Example code is below. I've defined the variable cost_counter at the beginning. The function below goes on for longer, but I'm just including the first part for an example of what is happening.

```
cost_counter <<- matrix(0,nrow = 2, ncol = 12*15)
I0 <- function(){
if (screen[i] == 1){
  cost_counter[2,ages[i]] <<- 1 + cost_counter[2,ages[i]] + 1
  if(HIV[i] == 1){
    if(ages[i] > 35){
      if(pv[(i-min_i+1),1] < (1-specP3)){
        cost_counter[1,ages[i]] <<- cost_counter[1,ages[i]] + 1
        if(contact[i] == 1){return(c(5,0))}
      }
    }
```

When I run, error message simply says 
"Error in cost_counter[2, ages[i]] <<- cost_counter[2, ages[i]] + 1 : 
  object 'cost_counter' not found"

I would just like to be able to modify the matrix, and for it to be recognized.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Not only is `<<-` not recommended but more importantly the approaches needing it (exactly what you are trying to do, i.e., modify an object outside the function scope) should generally be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

just at the end f the function re assign the function's matrix to the global env using:

```
cost_counter <<- cost_counter
```

Comment: This dosent seem to be helping, as the problem is when the matrix is called in the first place, and anything further downstream may not be iterated through due to returns terminating it.